# Jboss version with single line command in unix

Tags: jboss, middleware

Can you please let me know how can i Jboss version running in my servers, i am not able to find standalone.sh script file in some of the servers. is there any log or single command to find out Jboss.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To find out which version of EAP you have installed on machine, grep `jboss-modules.jar`. Called as `$JBOSS_HOME`. Once you location of EAP installer i.e `$JBOSS_HOME`, you will find `version.txt` at same location which will tell you exact version of EAP.

If you already know location of EAP, chekc `version.txt` to know the exact version of EAP or grep server.log file present in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log